# How do you restore the intrinsic permissions associated with a bucket in GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform

I was using Terraform's `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` instead of `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` to apply permissions which resulted in all the default permissions including the intrinsic permissions that project viewers, editors, and owners have (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#basic-roles-intrinsic). I was able to use `terraform destroy` to undo the authoritative `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy`; however, the intrinsic permissions have not been restored. I tried adding these three permissions back using the console but there's no viewer, editor, or owner group. The only thing I see is `allUsers` and `allAuthenticatedUsers`. Is there a way to restore these permissions either manually or automatically without deleting the bucket entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform following commands:

```
gsutil acl ch -p editors-<project number>:O gs://<bucket name>
gsutil acl ch -p owners-<project number>:O gs://<bucket name>
gsutil acl ch -p viewers-<project number>:R gs://<bucket name>
```